# Open Tab using Workspace API

Tags: lightning, aura, workspaceapi

I am getting error while trying to use workspace api and open tab using lightning quick action. I created a flex page and Assigned it to two different Apps in salesforce one standard service console app and another custom application. Flexpage is visible to only in Service console app and for the custom application I am getting following error " Error: API `openTab` is not currently supported in this application". I am trying to find out ways to create subtabs on the custom application where user have access to page where they navigated from in the same window

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't use the Workspace API outside a console application - there is no workspace. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to display lwc component on a button click but user wanted to display it on subtab under the account.

Comment: There are no subtabs if you aren't in a console application. What, specifically, are you asking the community to help with? Could you please [edit] your post to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Subtabs are part of the Console application framework. You cannot access the Workspace API or create subtabs in a non-console-based application.

You create *browser* tabs; see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786813/input-onclick-new-tab) on Stack Overflow, or your preferred HTML reference.